# Jenkins job triggers multiple times for git push

Tags: jenkins, github-api

The question is about one of my jenkins job which should be triggered for every push on github. Yes, the job is getting triggered for every push on github but it is running multiple times repeatedly. When I see the console output of those executions, I can see it is triggering for very older commits lets say commits which were done 1 or 2 years ago in the repository. (I need to trigger the job only for recent commit). One of my job ran repeatedly thousands of times while there aren't thousand commit in my repo.

I have mentioned '**' in the 'Branch Specifier' of SCM section. (I cannot write particular branch name as I need to run the job for every new branch and every new push on any existing branch), if I mention the particular branch name, it works fine but not for '**'.

I am using github-api version 1.90 and github plugin 1.29.4.

I searched for solutions and only could get the answer to remove '**' and write the branch name which in my case will not work for any new branch or branch other than one which is written in job.

On github side, I have this:

```
 Settings -> Webhooks & Services -> Services
 Select Jenkins (GitHub plugin) 
 Jenkins Hook Url: http://********/github-webhook/
```

And in my Jenkins job:

```
 GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling
```

Comment: I think you have selected wrong option in "Let me select individual events." panel in GitHub setting page. can you share the more about configuration details?

Comment: Thanks for answering, on the github setting page I have selected 'Just the push event.'. Well, I just now tried one solution which it to specify 'refs/heads/**' as Branch Specifier and it is working as expected. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning 'refs/heads/**' as Branch Specifier solved my problem.